# Virtual Audio Device from iTunes

Tags: itunes, audio

For some audio-reaction projects I wish to output audio virtually from iTunes and not from microphone. Actually Loopback just manages to do the job sufficiently, but therefore it's costly to enjoy the full version

[image]

Instead I tried an application called Blackhole, but it my view it's not able to input sound from iTunes directly:

[image]

Therefor I wonder if only Loopback has got the privilege routing audio this way or if it's somehow possible to choose from free devices ?

Note: I want to route iTunes audio -> input inbuilt microphone (I guess it's the one built in the iMac inside). As far as I understand the program I'm running only uses the microphone sound. That's why I need to create a virtual microphone that uses iTunes sound as if someone speaks. This is exactly what Loopback manages doing.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to route to where. Output from iTunes -> where? Your Loopback image looks like you just have it routed to 'built-in output' which I'm assuming is a mini-jack out? 'Not from microphone'… do you want to route this anywhere or just have it silenced?

Comment: Hi, I want to route iTunes audio -> input inbuilt microphone (I guess it's the one built in the iMac inside). As far as I understand the program I'm running only uses the microphone sound. That's why I need to create a virtual microphone that uses iTunes sound as if someone speaks. This is exactly what Loopback manages doing.

Comment: You cannot route an output to the mic. That breaks the laws of physics. Please tell us what you are trying to do, not how you already decided you need to do it. e.g. "I need to run output from iTunes to input of… *xyx* " We at least must know what your xyz app is.

Comment: I need a virtual audio source as it is described in this project on the bottom of the page: https://github.com/scottlawsonbc/audio-reactive-led-strip

Comment: OK. Sorry, that's something I have no way to test.

Comment: I think the difference is that Blackhole will redirect the all outputted sound as input, where as Loopback can redirect just outputted sound from iTunes or other application as input